# What are ways a debug statement could "fix" bugs in a program?

Tags: theory

In a recent interview, I was asked the following question:

> > You have a bug in your program, after attempting to debug it by inserting statements like printf, console.log, System.out.println, echo, etc, the bug disappears. How can this happen?

I responded with answers like the following:

- You have something with side effects in the print statement, eg: `System.out.println(foo.somethingWithSideEffects())`
- Adding printf changes the memory layout of the program, therefore it could cover adjacent memory and prevent crashes
- Undefined Behavior in native code (like uninitialized values, buffer overruns, sequence points, etc)

The interviewer said those aren't the only ways that this could happen, and I couldn't think of any other ways simply adding a printf, etc could "fix" a bug in a program.

What other things could cause this to happen?

Comment: I'd say the interviewer did you a disservice if he made that statement and didn't expand upon it.

Comment: You should read this INRIA paper ([The pitfalls of verifying floating-point computations](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/182252/filename/floating-point-article.pdf)), which covers the perverse behaviour of floating-point numbers near function calls on some compilers. Of note: _As an example, simply inserting a `printf("%g\n", y);` call after the computation of `y` in the above `square` function forces `y` to be spilt to memory, and thus the final result then becomes `+∞` regardless of optimisation_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest thing that comes to mind is that putting debugging code in can change the timing of the code, which can matter if there is a race condition in the code being debugged. It can be very frustrating to try to debug race conditions that disappear when inspected like this.

Answer (score 0):

That could be happen because of memory overflowing , or there could be system interrupt while the program running.If you cannot really attach the debug so you may write eventlogs but it should be the last way to do i think

Comment: "If you cannot really attach the debug"? What? Are you suggesting that attaching a debugger would be _less_ likely to change the behaviour of code than debugging output? That is not true in my experience